# Invalid Expression Term '='

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Sorta just messing with javascript and hoping that this would work..

Using asp.net textboxes and trying to change the values of the disabled ones with the math calculations of the enabled ones.. I thought maybe I was concatenating and that was the 
error but it's not even hitting the math, skipping straight from ().value = to the error..

The error is hitting on page load before I get to do anything and my button has:

```
<input type="button" onclick="chkMath()"/>
```

I did try an asp button too but that didn't work so this is what I have for now.

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function chkMath() {
        // cust id doesn't need variable
        // var a = document.getElementById('<%=f0.ClientID%>').value;
        var b = document.getElementById('<%=f1.ClientID%>').value;
        var c = document.getElementById('<%=f2.ClientID%>').value;
        var d = document.getElementById('<%=f4.ClientID%>').value;
        var e = document.getElementById('<%=f5.ClientID%>').value;
        var f = document.getElementById('<%=f6.ClientID%>').value;
        var g = document.getElementById('<%=f8.ClientID%>').value;
        var h = document.getElementById('<%=f9.ClientID%>').value;
        var i = document.getElementById('<%=f11.ClientID%>').value;
        var j = document.getElementById('<%=f12.ClientID%>').value;

        document.getElementById('<%#=f3.ClientID%>').value = b - c;
        document.getElementById('<%#=f7.ClientID%>').value = e + f;
        document.getElementById('<%#=f10.ClientID%>').value = g + h;
        document.getElementById('<%#=f13.ClientID%>').value = b - i;
        document.getElementById('<%#=f14.ClientID%>').value = d - j;
    }
</script>
```

Using the getElementByID(''); syntax I found on asp.net

Anyway don't know what's going on here, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your script is defined before the html of your page?

Comment: `<%#=` invalid. It is an ASP.NET error.

Comment: Why did you use `'<%#=f3.ClientID%>'` the "#" in those?

Comment: Put the script tag just before the body ending tag and check if you get the same error again?

Comment: @Adil that code is in a function so it doesn't matter where the `<script>` is (probably).

Comment: Pointy was right..  but now I have some weird error on line 598? The page isn't even 250 lines long... I'll add it into ot, edit: the page works now because of the answers.. I just mixed up some things because I've been using a lot of gridviews

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<%#=` is invalid, and it is an ASP.NET error; naught to do with JavaScript.

The binding expression seen by ASP.NET after parsing is `=f3.ClientID` which results in "Invalid Expression Term '='".

Comment: fixed, thanks.. now have to figure out why subtraction ones work and addition ones concatenate

Comment: @pbrianq Strings are concatenated with `+` (if either expression is a string). Use `parseInt/parseFloat` or the unary `+`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a #= when you should be using just =

should be

```
document.getElementById('<%=f3.ClientID%>').value = b - c;
```

the # is used during databinding expressions. = is used to directly inject content into your html output, which is what you want to do here

Answer (score 1):

There is no construct as `<%#=f3.ClientID%>` in ASP.NET web forms. `<%# something %>` is used for data-binding.

What you want is `<%= something %>` which is equivalent to

```
<% Response.Write(something)%>
```

So remove the `#` from these line and it will work as you want. Like this:

```
document.getElementById('<%=f3.ClientID%>').value = b - c;
document.getElementById('<%=f7.ClientID%>').value = e + f;
document.getElementById('<%=f10.ClientID%>').value = g + h;
document.getElementById('<%=f13.ClientID%>').value = b - i;
document.getElementById('<%=f14.ClientID%>').value = d - j;
```